# Size class does not works

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

[image][image]I need to create an app with adaptive UI. for that I use auto layout and size class. but i can't get the expected result. it displays different UIs for different screen sizes. kindly guide me to create the adaptive UI(for all screen sizes). Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some images or expected result and also post what you tried till now and what you get?

Comment: is the `Use SizeClasses` checkbox checked for Main.storyboard file?

Comment: @Bhavin jst w8 I ll upload the images

Comment: @VinayJain yes its checked

Comment: size classes are working, you haven't added constraints for the imageView

Comment: that image is the screenshot of 6plus. if I run it in 6,5s or 5 it displays differently...

Comment: @VinayJain could u please guide me to set the constraints? I have already added the default constraints

Comment: @Bhavin added the screenshot of 4s

Comment: @Bhavin you are correct but the total ui is colapsed here am askin solution for that

Comment: ya it happens because of your constraints not able to handle all size classes...that means the problem is with your constraints...not with the size classes...

Comment: @Bhavin please guide me to set the constraints

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed problem with constraints as mentioned in comments to your question. Using size classes only allows you to set constraints for all iphones at lowest level (that's why screen size for size class Compact x Regular is same for all iphones in xcode).

It is difficult to help you, without knowing all of your constraints. My advice is, use Preview assistant, where you can see all of your devices and generated UI. By opening this Preview assistant, tap on bottom "+" symbol and add device you wish to inspect.

[image: opening preview assistant]

[image: attached xCode screenshot]

As you can see on this screenshot, in my storyboard, there are margins around the middle view, however on iPhone 4, where width is smaller, these margins are lower (they have lower priority as constraint), while view retains it's width/height.